# sapply to dataframe and remove colum index

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to get unique counts for each column in my dataframe and output a dataframe with the counts

```
library(dplyr) 

data %>%
  sapply(n_distinct) %>%
  data.frame()

  .
Q 2
D 4
G 2
A 2
```

I want my output to be like this though

```
col  count
Q    2
D    4
G    2
A    2
```

how can i remove the column index and change the column name from . to "count" in tidy syntax?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of ``data``.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% sapply(n_distinct) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  rename('col'='rowname','count'='.')
```

**output;**

```
           col count
1 Sepal.Length    35
2  Sepal.Width    23
3 Petal.Length    43
4  Petal.Width    22
5      Species     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), n_distinct)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "col", values_to = "count")
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  col          count
  <chr>        <int>
1 Sepal.Length    35
2 Sepal.Width     23
3 Petal.Length    43
4 Petal.Width     22
5 Species          3
```

Or

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  map_df(~ tibble(count = n_distinct(.x)),
         .id = "col")
```